# Custom request.querystring URL rewriting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url

Can anyone please provide me the details how we can implement custom URL rewriting in asp.net

This is my request id string url:

*mypage.com/productdetail.aspx?id=1*

and now i would like it to redirect below URL:

*mypage.com/productdetail/productname*

Please help me.

p.s I'm sorry if  it 's a stupid question. Please let me know if u guys need  further informations.

Thank in advance, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Look into `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`. It's a Nuget package that might well already be installed on your project and it should be able to help you.

Comment: thank you, but it's sad that I'm using VS 2008 :(

Comment: Have a look at this link. It explains how to do that with examples. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

Use Request.PathInfo Parameters Instead of QueryStrings see the below Link it might be useful

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net